# Facebook - Weekly summary

Tags: facebook

I spend too much time on Facebook. Are there any tools that would allow me to get a Weekly Summary of the posts in my newsfeed that got the most activity?

Answer (score 2):

So far, Facebook develops **Facebook Insights**.

> [Facebook Insights](https://www.facebook.com/insights) is a tool for
>   those wanting to track user interaction on your **Facebook Page**.
>   **Facebook Insights** can be seen by all the admins of your page and it can help you track the number of active users to better understand
>   page performance. Page Insights gives page managers a number of
>   aggregate metrics, including the *number of people who like* their
>   Page, how many *people see a post* and how many *people clicked the
>   post*.

Related with your question, Facebook only has that tool for your page, not your activity (even your log activity). Maybe, there was a tool tracking your activity out there which developed by someone. But, it's possible Facebook develops next tool for tracking your activity (your summary) like [Twitter Analytics](https://analytics.twitter.com/about).